# Differences between `torch.Tensor` and `torch.cuda.Tensor`

Tags: pytorch

We can allocate a tensor on GPU using `torch.Tensor([1., 2.], device='cuda')`. Are there any differences using that way rather than `torch.cuda.Tensor([1., 2.])`, except we can pass in a specific CUDA device to the former one?

Or in other words, in which scenario is `torch.cuda.Tensor()` necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So generally both `torch.Tensor` and `torch.cuda.Tensor` are equivalent. You can do everything you like with them both.

The key difference is just that `torch.Tensor` occupies *CPU* memory while `torch.cuda.Tensor` occupies *GPU* memory. Of course operations on a *CPU Tensor* are computed with *CPU* while operations for the *GPU / CUDA Tensor* are computed on *GPU*.

The reason you need these two tensor types is that the underlying hardware interface is completely different. Apart from the point it doesn't make sense computationally, you will get an error as soon as you try to do computations between `torch.Tensor` and `torch.cuda.Tensor`:

```py
import torch

# device will be 'cuda' if a GPU is available
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# creating a CPU tensor
cpu_tensor = torch.rand(10)
# moving same tensor to GPU
gpu_tensor = cpu_tensor.to(device)

print(cpu_tensor, cpu_tensor.dtype, type(cpu_tensor), cpu_tensor.type())
print(gpu_tensor, gpu_tensor.dtype, type(gpu_tensor), gpu_tensor.type())

print(cpu_tensor*gpu_tensor)
```

Output:

```py
tensor([0.8571, 0.9171, 0.6626, 0.8086, 0.6440, 0.3682, 0.9920, 0.4298, 0.0172,
        0.1619]) torch.float32 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.FloatTensor
tensor([0.8571, 0.9171, 0.6626, 0.8086, 0.6440, 0.3682, 0.9920, 0.4298, 0.0172,
        0.1619], device='cuda:0') torch.float32 <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.cuda.FloatTensor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ac794171c178> in <module>()
     12 print(gpu_tensor, gpu_tensor.dtype, type(gpu_tensor), gpu_tensor.type())
     13 
---> 14 print(cpu_tensor*gpu_tensor)

RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.FloatTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'other'
```

As the underlying hardware interface is completely different, CPU Tensors are just compatible with CPU Tensor and verse visa GPU Tensors are just compatible to GPU Tensors.

*Edit:*

*As you can see here that a tensor which is moved to GPU is actually a tensor of type: `torch.cuda.*Tensor` i.e. `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.*

*So `cpu_tensor.to(device)` or `torch.Tensor([1., 2.], device='cuda')` will actually return a tensor of type `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.*

***In which scenario is `torch.cuda.Tensor()` necessary?***

When you want to use GPU acceleration *(which is much faster in **most** cases)* for your program, you need to use `torch.cuda.Tensor`, but you have to make sure that **ALL** tensors you are using are CUDA Tensors, mixing is not possible here.

Comment: I see the differences from your design of neural network framework view. But what I am still confusing is why we can't just use `torch.Tensor` with the attribute `device` to identify its location? Like the example I given, if we can use the method `torch.Tensor([1., 2.], device='cuda')`, which is widely used, including  both `cpu` and `cuda` allocation, why the designers specificlly design  a `torch.cuda.Tensor` type? (I think something like `torch.FloatTensor, device=cuda` is enough).

Comment: @lincr Please check the edited example *(the print statements)* and the edit I made below. Does this answer your question?

Comment: ,Yes, finally I got the answer. Actually I have checked the source code before seeking help here, trying to find the relation between the two types, but failed to locate related code. As you pointed out, `torch.Tensor`  seems like an application of  simple factory pattern, which will call the constructor  of corresponding cuda tensor if `device` parameter is given. Thank you for your timely and detailed explanation!